# Suppose $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are functions so that $g\circ f:X\to Z$ is bijective and $g$ is injective. Show that $f$ is a bijection.

Tags: functions

I know that for a function to be a bijection it has to be both injective and surjective but how do I prove it in this question?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show that $g$ must be surjective. Then $f=g^{-1}\circ(g\circ f)$ and use that fact that composition of two bijections is again a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

To show $f$ is injective: If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ and so we must have $x=y$ (since $g\circ f$ is injective).

To show $f$ is surjective: Let $y\in Y$ and let $z=g(y)$. Since $g\circ f$ is surjective, there is some $x\in X$ such that $g(f(x))=z$. But $g$ is injective, so we can conclude that $f(x)=y$. (I'll leave this last part as an exercise for you to check)